# Why the product is wrong

Tags: organic-chemistry

In the followig reaction .

I predict a product .

That is [image]

but that is wrong I could not understand why .

Answer (score 8):

The most acidic proton is attached to the carbon bearing the nitro group so treatment with $\ce{OH-}$ will remove that and then eliminate $\ce{F-}$ giving the nitro-alkene.

Answer (score 0):

**Elimination of a poor leaving group such as F proceeds through E1CB mechanism.**

Now here, the base $\ce{OH-}$ would abstract the proton from the site where the negative charge would be best stabilised (i.e. most acidic proton) which happens to be from the carbon bearing the nitro group, as $\ce{NO2}$ group is a strong electron withdrawing group, hence after abstraction of proton by the base, the negative charge attacks the nearest electron deficient carbon (i.e. the one bonded to $\ce{F}$) as $\ce{F}$ is also a good electron withdrawing group (Note: $\ce{F}$ pulls electrons through -I effect only, whereas $\ce{NO2}$ can do the same through -R effect when the negative charge is on the carbon bonded to it). Thus the negative charge expells the $\ce{F}$ atom as $\ce{F-}$ ion, which results in formation of a double bond between the two carbons.

Giving you the final product as $\ce{CH3-CH=CH2-NO2}$